# Yii where to put a custom global function?

Tags: yii

I created a `is_home_page()` function to detect if a user is on the homepage or not, but i'm not sure where i should put it so i can be used on all views and themes?

```
function is_home_page() {
    $app = Yii::app();
    return $app->controller->route == $app->defaultController;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

create a file a MyClass.php inside components

You can write the static functions inside like

```
public static function is_home_page() {
        $app = Yii::app();
         return $app->controller->route == $app->defaultController;
     }
```

which can be accessed from any where like controller, Model or View as below

```
MyClass::is_home_page();
```

hope this will help you to write any number of functions globally and access them from anywhere

Comment: sweet, don't have to edit anything in `config/main.php` too! thanks!

Answer (score 8):

make a file helpers.php and put it inside components folder

protected

           |-components

                |-helpers.php

And add this line in the top of your config main.php file

```
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/../components/helpers.php');
```

and inside that helpers.php write your function

```
<?php
     function is_home_page() {
        $app = Yii::app();
         return $app->controller->route == $app->defaultController;
     }

?>
```

Now this function is accessible in whole application directly call is_home_page() any where and it will return your value.

Comment: should i set an alias for it? `Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', dirname(__FILE__) . '/../components/helpers.php');` ?

Comment: not necessary if it can be done simply then why you will do like that.

Answer (score 1):

You may create class `Globals` with all helpers method. For example:

```
   class Globals{
       public function is_home_page() {
           $app = Yii::app();
           return $app->controller->route == $app->defaultController;
       }
   }
```

than in `main.php` section `components` set:

```
  'globals' => array(
       'class' => 'alias.to.location.Globals'
  )
```

than in code you may use this `Yii::app()->globals->is_home_page()`

Comment: in `protected/components/Helpers.php` right? and `alias.to.location.Globals` would be `application.components.Helpers` ?

Comment: why not put it in `'import'=>array()` in main.php?

Comment: Better set name for file as `Globals.php` (file name must equals name of class). Than if class will be in `protected/components/Globals.php` than alias `application.components.Globals`

Comment: Because if you add it to import, than you need always create an object of Globals for using method is_home_page in different places. For using globally you must place it in components of Yii

Answer (score -1):

For Yii 2.0, please refer to this article:

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/747/write-use-a-custom-component-in-yii2-0/

---

I am editing this for test purpose.